# C# file directory tree

Tags: c#, file

Can anyone explain for me what's that means,I want to move one folder up

```
 ../
 ./
 /
 ~
```

For example

`Server.MapPath("../deneme.txt");` Is this code true for move directory to parent directory

Comment: Not all web servers will support the `..` syntax as it's a security risk.  You may need an explicit path.

Comment: two dots `..` for parent, single dot `.` for current and `/` for root. It is same in DOS

Comment: This is something you might see in a command line, not in a C# program...

Answer (score 5):

You can use [System.IO.Directory.GetParent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent.aspx) to retrieve the parent directory of a given directory.

[System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for current directory